# dynamically add button column in Asp.net GridView using Jquery

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, gridview

I have populated Grid View Dynamically with json Data ..Button Column started to appears only in First Row ..But not in below rows  ..

I have Tried Code to add column in server side code as well as in Mark Up ..I also search but could not able to find any thing relevant

this is my MarkUp :

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                url: "List.aspx/GetData",
                data: "{}",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (data) {
                    for (var i = 0; i < data.d.length; i++) {
                        $("#gvDetails").append("<tr><td>" + data.d[i].c1 + "</td><td>" + data.d[i].c2 + "</td><td>" + "</td></tr>");
                    }
                },
                error: function (result) {
                    alert(result.status + ' ' + result.statusText);
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:GridView ID="gvDetails" runat="server" ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="True">
            <Columns>
                <asp:ButtonField Text="Button" />
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
```

this is code behind :

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            BindColumnToGridview();
        }

        private void BindColumnToGridview()
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Columns.Add("c1");
            dt.Columns.Add("c2");

            dt.Rows.Add();
            gvDetails.DataSource = dt;

            gvDetails.DataBind();

        }


        [WebMethod]
        [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
        public static tbl1[] GetData()
        {

            try
            {
                using (var context = new TestDBContext())
                {
                    List<tbl1> lsTbl1 = new List<tbl1>();

                    lsTbl1 = (from c in context.tbl1 select c).ToList();
                    return lsTbl1.ToArray();

                }
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {

                throw;
            }

        }
```

I also tried to add column from code behind

```
gvDetails.Columns.Add(new ButtonField() { Text = "Button"  });
```

this is not working too

any sugestion will be helpful

Answer (score 1):

Since `gvDetails` is a server side control you should use `<%= gvDetails.ClientID %>` in your JS snippet.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                url: "List.aspx/GetData",
                data: "{}",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (data) {
                    for (var i = 0; i < data.d.length; i++) {
                        $("#<%= gvDetails.ClientID %>").append("<tr><td>" + data.d[i].c1 + "</td><td>" + data.d[i].c2 + "</td><td>" + "</td></tr>");
                    }
                },
                error: function (result) {
                    alert(result.status + ' ' + result.statusText);
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
```

**EDIT:**

[image]

Comment: I did that ..But still button column not visible

Comment: @neeraj It is working at my end. Please try logging data.d in your console.

Comment: No NO ..that also i am getting ..I want Button in each Row in first column..thats the problem